# Matrix representation of the operator $A$ with $\frac{d}{dt}U(t)=AU(t)$

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, operator-theory

Consider the following equations

\begin{eqnarray}
u_{tt}+(u_{xx}-\phi u_t)_{xx}&=&0, \quad (l_0,l_1)\times(0,\infty)\\
v_{tt}-v_{xx}+\psi v_t&=&0,\quad (l_1,l_2)\times(0,\infty)\\
u(x,0)=u_0,\, u_t(x,0)&=&u_1\quad (l_0,l_1)\\
v(x,0)=v_0,\, v_t(x,0)&=&v_1 \quad (l_1,l_2)
\end{eqnarray}

whit $\phi(x),\psi(x)>0$ in $(l_0,l_1)$ ,$(l_1,l_2)$ respectively.

I want to show that the previous problem is well defined, i.e, the problem has unique solution treating it as an abstract Cauchy problem. I have to represent the problem as $\frac{d}{dt}U(t)=AU(t)$.

If $U=(u,v,w,z)^T$, then I define the system operator as $AU=(w,z,-(u_{xx}-\phi w)_{xx},v_{xx}-\psi z)^T$. Now, if $U(t)=(u,v,u_t,v_t)^T$ it follows that
$$\frac{d}{dt}U(t)=AU(t)=(u_t,v_t,-(u_{xx}-\phi u_t)_{xx},v_{xx}-\psi v_t)^T$$

It is a fact that I have to find the domain of the operator $A$, but my question is: Can I write the operator $A$ in matrix form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing $$-(u_{xx}-\phi u_t)_{xx}=-\partial_x^4 u+\partial_{x}^2 (\phi u_t)$$
it would seem that

$$
AU(t)
=\begin{pmatrix} u_t \\ v_t\\ -\partial_{x}^4 u+\partial_{x}^2(\phi u_t) \\ \partial_x^2 v-\psi v_t\end{pmatrix}
 = 
\begin{pmatrix}
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
 -\partial_x^4 & 0 & \partial_x^2\phi & 0 \\
 0 & \partial_x^2 & 0 & -\psi
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} u \\ v \\ u_t \\ v_t\end{pmatrix}
$$
where $ \partial_x^2 \phi = \phi_{xx}+2\phi_x\partial_x+\phi \partial_x^2$ has been used to simplify the typesetting.

Comment: Why do you extract $\phi$ from the derivative in the first vector?

Comment: @CharlesXavier Typo, fixed.

Comment: The matrix acts like the usual multiplication between matrix and vector? I mean $(\phi_{xx}+2\phi_x\partial_x+\phi \partial_x^2)u_t= (\phi_{xx}u_t+2\phi_x\partial_x(u_t)+\phi\partial_x^2 (u_t))$.

Just the differential operator acts like composition and everything else act like multiplication of functions?

Comment: @CharlesXavier Correct. However, I do notice a possible typo: Your original set of equations had $v_{tt}-v_{xx}+\psi u_t=0$. But in that case, that should mean the last entry in $AU$ should be $v_{xx}-\psi u_t$ not $v_{xx}-\psi v_t$. (That's easy to change in the matrix $A$ but makes a big difference in your equations.)